# Import a couple hundred images and place them side-by side in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I am trying to create a sequence just like this:

[image: sequence of images]

[Link](http://cf.squarespace.com/details/chef-hand-sequence-hires.png)

The issue is, my sequence is much longer: 439 frames. I have the PNG files, I just need to merge them to be side-by-side like it is in the link. I've tried fiddling around with using actions and droplets, but I can't get it to behave like I want. How can I do it?

Comment: Is Photoshop a hard requirement or are you open to other solutions?

Comment: Expanding on JohnB's comment - InDesign has a built in script for this.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend Imagemagick as the appropriate tool here. It has a high learning curve, but is much faster than Photoshop for this sort of batch processing. The following commands should work:

`convert inputFolder/* +append output.png`

where inputFolder is a folder containing only the images you're interested in. They should be named in sequence (001, 002, 003...)

If you want to add padding between the images (in this case 5 pixels to the left and right edges), try this:

`montage inputFolder/* -tile x1 -geometry +5+0 tile.png`

If you can't use Imagemagick, a Google search for "Photoshop Filmstrip Script" yields many results, such as [**this one**](http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=2489).

Comment: works like a charm thank you. is there any way to add a little padding after each image?

Comment: Sure. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my script can tell you what to do: [gist](https://gist.github.com/amolok/d5e3ed709b18adb536da)

Loading stack of images (one layer above another):

```
function loadStack(name,size){
var d;
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var fileNum = sprintf("%05d",i);
    var f = new File(sourcePath+'fr'+name+'_'+fileNum+'.png');
// you can use your own file selection
    if(i==0){
// operating on first file in sequence
        app.open(f);
        d = app.activeDocument;
        d.activeLayer.name = fileNum;
    }else{
// adding file content to new layer
        d.artLayers.add();
        d.activeLayer.name = fileNum;
        app.open(f);
        app.activeDocument.selection.selectAll();
        app.activeDocument.selection.copy();
        app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
        d.paste();
    }
}
}
```

Next I simply `do rows` with my stack:

```
function doRows(rows,cols){
var d = app.activeDocument;
var w = d.width;
var h = d.height;
d.resizeCanvas(w*cols,h*rows,AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT);
for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
// using numbered layers
        var fileNum = sprintf("%05d", j*rows+i );
        d.artLayers.getByName(fileNum).translate(w*j, h*i);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

manually doing this is going to be your best bet. Turn on guides, turn on rulers, drop a guide at the edge of each new frame you add... and get some coffee. The fluctuations in image size and the nature of taxing memory on something this massive at the speed of an action mean that humanly doing this is likely to work better.

There maybe many "work-arounds" to your end goal that are faster. Can you describe that end goal?